# Is there any way to set a special character in MySQL database record?

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, bulkinsert

I used CodeIgniter for my back end technology. I just create one bulk insertion module for reading CSV data and insert it in the database.

But in insertion do not insert proper value like:-

**Wrong value:- Brhl Castle**

**Right value:- Brühl Castle**

**Is there any way to insert the same value in a database like the right value?**

In Controller my code like this:-

```
$dataIn['title'] = utf8_encode($data[1]);
$dataIn['latitude'] = $data[2];
$dataIn['longitude'] = $data[3];
$dataIn['country'] = utf8_encode($data[4]);
$dataIn['city'] = utf8_encode($data[5]);
$this->model->bulkInsert($dataIn);
```

In Model my code like this:-

```
function bulkInsert($dataIn, $id = '') {
    $this->db->where(array('id' => $dataIn['id']));
    $query = $this->db->get($this->TABLE);
    $result = $query->row_array();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $this->db->where($this->PK, $dataIn['id']);
        $this->db->update($this->TABLE, $dataIn);
    } else {
        $this->db->insert($this->TABLE, $dataIn);
    }
    setMessage('Record inserted successfully.', 'green');
}
```

Comment: set the mysql field collation to UTF8_general_ci

Comment: Thanks for your reply,It's working perfectly now.